# Refs in mount/update component lifecycle

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an infinite scrolling list that scrolls in both directions. The list presents a 5 item-per-row grid that represents the 5 work days in a 7 day week. The days are zebra stripped by month (even months have a slightly darker color). I want to position the month title in a column to the left of the grid, starting at the first day of the month, or the earliest day available for the month (given the AJAXed in data -- does not always start with the first weekday of the month).

I have all the necessary logic in place to figure out which day is the first day (as I'm only showing weekdays, if the first falls on a weekend, then the start of the month might not be the first).

I have the following so far:

1. When rendering the grid, tag the beginning of the month and the end of the month with a `ref` in the format of `YYYYMM_start` or `YYYYMM_end`.
2. I then render the `MonthTitle` component with a `monthStamp` prop that is in the same format of `YYYYMM`, as well as a `findMonthNode` prop that receives a function to lookup the start and end node on the parent component (using regex).
3. In the `MonthTitle` component, in `componentDidMount`, I can then position the title absolutely relative to the start node for that month. I also invoke the exact same function in `componentDidUpdate`.

My issue is when I scroll the list (remember, infinite scroll in both directions) back in time: my AJAX fires and loads in the new tiles with the new month titles, and the new month titles render appropriately, but the first of the original titles does NOT update accordingly. After some poking around, I realized that `this.refs` in the parent component in `componentDidUpdate` ***does not equal*** `this.refs` in the parent component in `componentDidMount`. `componentDidMount` seems to have the complete list, whereas `componentDidUpdate` only has the list of nodes that existed before the new nodes (from the AJAX response) have been mounted.

Since `componentDidUpdate` does not have all the new refs, I cannot position the previously first month title accordingly, and it remains stuck where it was initially rendered in `componentDidMount`, which--given the new data--is now the incorrect position.

---

Why is `this.refs` different in these two functions (`componentDidMount` & `componentDidUpdate`)? What can I do to ensure that I have access to the complete `this.refs` when mounting AND updating components?

Using `react 0.13.3` FYI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out a solution. Instead of `MonthTitle` handling its own position during its lifecycle callbacks (`componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`), I am having their parent component (`Grid`) invoke methods on the titles to position them in the parent's `componentDidUpdate`.

So, roughly, in `Grid`, I have the following:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  for (let [ref, component] of entries(this.refs)) {
    if (/_title$/.test(ref)) {
      var startOfMonthNode = React.findDOMNode(findRef("startOfMonth", this.refs, component.props.monthStamp))
      var endOfMonthNode = React.findDOMNode(findRef("endOfMonth", this.refs, component.props.monthStamp))

      component.position(startOfMonthNode, endOfMonthNode)
    }
  }
}
```

Then, inside my `MonthTitle` component, I define the positioning logic:

```
position(startOfMonthNode, endOfMonthNode) {
  React.findDOMNode(this).style["top"] = getDimension((startOfMonthNode || endOfMonthNode), "top") + window.scrollY - 116 + "px"
}
```

This means that I had to add the titles themselves to my `refs` list in `Grid`.

---

So, conceptually, the difference was moving ***when*** the positioning updates happened from the child component's lifecycle to the parent component's lifecycle. Since the parent component's `componentDidUpdate` will fire after any new child components have been mounted, I have the complete list of `refs` available.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the component lifecycle specs [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#lifecycle-methods), you will see that `componentDidUpdate` is run every time your component has been updated (via `this.setState` in either the component or one of its ancestors), but not after the initial render:

> `componentDidUpdate(object prevProps, object prevState)`
>
> Invoked immediately after the component's updates are flushed to the
>   DOM. This method is not called for the initial render.

`componentDidMount` on the other hand is run after the initial render, but not after updates via `setState`:

> `componentDidMount()`
>
> Invoked once, only on the client (not on the server), immediately
>   after the initial rendering occurs.

So if you update your state (via `this.setState` in your component) and re-render your component, potentially adding new child elements that have `ref` attributes, those will not be visible in the parent's `componentDidMount` but in `componentDidUpdate`.

On the other hand, if you update your parent component and the update renders new child components, those child components' `componentDidMount` will indeed fire before the parent's `componentDidUpdate` as the parent component is not done updating until all its new child components have mounted and rendered properly. It will go like this:

1. Any initial childrens' `componentDidMount` execute (somewhat surprising perhaps, but the parent isn't done mounting until all its children have mounted, which makes sense)
2. Parent's `componentDidMount` executes
3. Parent updates via `setState` with some added children and some children already existing from last render
4. All newly added childrens' `componentDidMount` execute and all previously existing childrens' `componentDidUpdate` execute
5. Parent's `componentDidUpdate` executes

[Here's a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/njj8bhpf/2/) demonstrating this.

Comment: The thing I'm still confused about is that `componentDidUpdate` seems to fire **before** `componentDidMount`, in that it flushes updates to the DOM before mounting the new nodes. Also, both the aforementioned methods are called for each instance of `MonthTitle`, which is a child to `Grid`. The `this.refs` in question exist on `Grid`, with an accessor method on `MonthTitle` to fetch the appropriate `ref`. if I put my positioning logic inside `Grid`'s `componentDidUpdate` instead of in `MonthTitle`, would that give me the complete `ref` list, you think?

Comment: Just posted my answer, as I realized I hadn't tried the approach I asked you about in that last question in my previous comment. Thanks for helping me think about this differently!

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution, however I'm curious: how come it appeared to you that `componentDidUpdate` was fired before `componentDidMount`? Were you looking at the wrong component? Because for each specific component, `componentDidUpdate` should never be able to be invoked before `componentDidMount`. If you mistook child components for the parent component, that's another story. I'll update my answer to explain this further in case it helps anyone else reading in the future.

Comment: The only thing that I noticed different from the steps you posted in your updated answer is step 4: in my experience, the existing child components' `componentDidUpdate` ***always fired before*** the new child components' `componentDidMount`. As all the children had a reference to a function on the parent to lookup the parent's `this.refs`, that meant that my logic in the child components' `componentDidUpdate` had an incomplete ref list. Does that clarify things?

Comment: "Any initial childrens' componentDidMount execute (somewhat surprising perhaps, but the parent isn't done mounting until all its children have mounted, which makes sense)" - thanks, I needed that